# Can scrapy skip the error of empty data and keeping scraping?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrape product pages from its sitemap, the products page are similar, but not all of them are the same.

for example

Product A
https://www.vitalsource.com/products/environment-the-science-behind-the-stories-jay-h-withgott-matthew-v9780134446400

Product B
https://www.vitalsource.com/products/abnormal-psychology-susan-nolen-hoeksema-v9781259765667

we can see the product A has the subtitle but another one doesn't have.

So I get errors when I trying to scrape all the product pages.

My question is, is there a way to let the spider skip the error for returning no data?

There is a simple way to bypass it. that is not using strip()
But I am wondering if there is a better way to do the job.

```
import scrapy
import re
from VitalSource.items import VitalsourceItem
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider



class VsSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'VS'
    allowed_domains = ['vitalsource.com']
    sitemap_urls = ['https://storage.googleapis.com/vst-stargate-production/sitemap/sitemap1.xml.gz']
    sitemap_rules = [
        ('/products/', 'parse_product'),
    ]
    def parse_product(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response=response)
        item = VitalsourceItem()
        item['Ebook_Title'] = response.css('.product-overview__title-header::text').extract()[1].strip
        item['Ebook_SubTitle'] = response.css("div.subtitle.subtitle-pdp::text").extract().strip
        print(item)
        return item
```

error message

```
    item['Ebook_SubTitle'] = response.css("div.subtitle.subtitle-pdp::text").extract().strip
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need only one subtitle you can use `get()` with setting default value to empty string. This will save you from errors about applying `strip()` function to empty element.

```
item['Ebook_SubTitle'] = response.css("div.subtitle.subtitle-pdp::text").get('').strip()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In general scrapy will not stop crawling if callbacks raise an exception. e.g.:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for i in range(10):
        yield Requst(
            f'http://example.org/page/{i}',
            callback=self.parse,
            errback=self.errback,
        )

def parse(self, response):
    # first page 
    if 'page/1' in response.request.url:
        raise ValueError()
    yield {'url': response.url}

def errback(self, failure): 
    print(f"oh no, failed to parse {failure.request}")
```

In this example 10 requests will be made and 9 items will be scraped but 1 will fail and got o `errback`

In your case you have nothing to fear - any request that does not raise an exception will scrape as it should, for the ones that do you'll just see an exception traceback in your terminal/logs.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could check if a value is returned before extracting:

```
if response.css("div.subtitle.subtitle-pdp::text"):
    item['Ebook_SubTitle'] = response.css("div.subtitle.subtitle-pdp::text").get().strip
```

That way the subTitle code line would only run if a value was to be returned...

Comment: Thank you for your help